# Does getStaticProps runs on the server?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to understand weather build time means when the page renders or when the app gets built into a vercel url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStaticProps` runs at build time unless you are using `revalidate` flag for `getStaticProps` or `fallback` flag for `getStaticPaths` (in this cases the page will be generated on request).